# What is the Big-O of this Anagram checker

Tags: javascript, big-o

This is a piece of code I wrote to check if two strings are anagrams. This is not homework, I am learning DS&A by myself.

It seems to me that the big-O should be O(N) because there are 2 separate for-loops, but the second for-loop worries me, specifically the `Object.entries()` call. Is the final time complexity  O(N) or O(N^2) here?

```
function isAnagram(origStr, checkStr) {

    if (origStr.length !== checkStr.length) {
        return false;
    }

    const origFreqCounter = {};
    const checkFreqCounter = {};

    let countFreq = (str, counter) => {
        for (const c of str) {
            counter[c] = counter[c] + 1 || 1;
        }    
    };

    countFreq(origStr, origFreqCounter);
    countFreq(checkStr, checkFreqCounter);

    // Is this O(N) or O(N^2)?
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(origFreqCounter)) {
        if (checkFreqCounter[key] !== value) return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}

console.log(isAnagram('', '')) // true
console.log(isAnagram('aaz', 'zza')) // false
console.log(isAnagram('anagram', 'nagaram')) // true
console.log(isAnagram("rat","car")) // false)
console.log(isAnagram('awesome', 'awesom')) // false
console.log(isAnagram('amanaplanacanalpanama', 'acanalmanplanpamana')) // false
console.log(isAnagram('qwerty', 'qeywrt')) // true
console.log(isAnagram('texttwisttime', 'timetwisttext')) // true
```

Comment: it misses of the equality test: if you test for the same string, the result should be false.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's `O(n)`.

This function iterates over the string's length, no nested loops:

```
let countFreq = (str, counter) => {
    for (const c of str) {
        counter[c] = counter[c] + 1 || 1;
    }    
};
```

That function is called twice, and not in a loop, so that's `O(n)`.

Then the `Object.entries` iterates over the entries of the `origFreqCounter` object. The `origFreqCounter` object will not have more entries than the number of characters in the `origStr` string, so that's also `O(n)`.

`O(n)` + `O(n)` + `O(n)` = `O(n)`.

Or, to be pedantic - the algorithm depends on the size of both `origStr` and `checkStr`, which are not necessarily the same, so it'd be [more proper](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25796205) to call it `O(n + m)`.